# MVC4 how to hook the OnSessionStart event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I start MVC4 project in VS2010,
In Global.asax.cs like :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth(); 
    }
}
```

how to register Session Start event ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just add this to your Global.asax.cs like this:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // event is raised each time a new session is created     
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // event is raised when a session is abandoned or expires
}
```

You should also probably check
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer@MonkeyCoder